# Excel 365 - Dynamically importing data into excel from a Database

Tags: microsoft-excel, database, sql, import, power-query

I have a spreadsheet with 40k rows or so which is added onto every week. Each row has an Employee ID, Employee’s Shift Number and Hours worked column (see attached image for sample data). [Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfxdc.jpg)

The problem is that I have the work out the Hours worked from a database to which I have an ODBC link setup to using SQL (The query would be something as follows:

```
SELECT hours_worked FROM employee_hrs WHERE employee_id = <employee id in excel> and shift_no = <Shift Number in excel>
```

My first instinct was to import the whole database table using Power Query into a separate worksheet and then use a 2 criteria index and match to find the house worked. The problem with this is that the database table has about 400k records (and increasing) so this approach is not efficient at all and is extremely slow since I end up using an array formula to lookup as well.

Is there a better, more efficient way of doing this so that the hours worked column is populated using the criteria above?

Many thanks in advance for your time and help!

Comment: The simplest method would be to issue the query using the database client software (which is what?).

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do. Is it summing hours worked by Employee_id and Shift_number?

Comment: I’m trying to get the hours worked from a database (which is an Oracle database and I usually access it using SQLDeveloper). 

So essentially, I need to get data from an oracle database table into the hours worked column using SQL with the criteria being employee id and shift number. It’s kind of like a lookup but from excel to the database table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a query against the Excel table containing 'Employee ID' and 'Shift Number', call it Query1. Use Home>Close & Load To>Create Connection Only

[image]

2. Create a query against the database table, say Query2, returning as few records and columns as possible. Use Home>Merge queries and configure like so:

[image]

Then use Home>Close & Load to put the result into a new sheet in your workbook.

This way, your Excel table becomes an external database table and your query is a view. When the Excel table is updated, you refresh the query. You don't have to use array formulas, vlookups etc